# Is there anyway to prevent from being defeated by a SS7 attack in android?

Tags: attacks

SS7 (Signalling System 7) is used by mobile operators to exchange information.

A flaw in SS7 allow hackers to access any calls and sms.

Is there any way to prevent from being a victim of SS7 from android?

Answer (score 2):

The PSTN is based on trust. If a third-party sends a call to your mobile provider pretending to be another number they don't own, your mobile provider will still happily trust it and forward the call to your mobile as if the call was from the legitimate owner of that number - your mobile has no way to tell whether something fishy is going on, and the mobile provider doesn't necessarily care about that either, though if they wanted they could mitigate at least some issues (like enforcing a whitelist - if the number isn't known to belong to the originating provider, refuse the call).

The only real mitigation is to not trust the mobile network and only use IP-based solutions which employ encryption - if you want to place calls do it either via something like FaceTime, WhatsApp, Facebook, etc - so the mobile network even if compromised wouldn't see much besides encrypted packets. Of course, this breaks down when you actually need to reach the PSTN - you could use a SIP provider (so at least you're protected against your mobile provider being malicious) but this shifts the issue down to the SIP provider where it could just as well be deceived into accepting a call from an impostor.